# Diagnosing dead laptop motherboard

Tags: laptop, motherboard

This may be a better question for the EE forum, but here goes.

Dell Inspiron 5000 17" laptop.  The user dropped a heavy object on the keyboard, immediately the laptop went off and won't power back on.  No lights, no fans -- nothing.

Disassembled and tested - power good to the board, and also the power button is live at 3.3V. 
No visible damage to the board - no loose/burnt/broken components that I can see.

How would you suggest to diagnose at this point?   I assume the starting point is the power circuitry.

Thx for any advice.

Comment: This is definitely a question for the EE forum. This site is mainly for questions about applications and operating systems, and other computer usage-based questions. Voting that this thread be closed.

Comment: Only when you gave up to fix it, try to heat it in a toaster (not a joke). There could be a case when some smd components lost contact. Heating would meltdown solder and restore connection. That would be great if you have IR thermometer to control temperature so you not exceed around 180C. Remove all plastic detachable details from MB. Don't preheat toaster, but start heating with motherboard inside, when temperature would be around 180C, decrease temperature gradually down and allow MB to cool down completely before removing from toaster.  This procedure helped to recover many "dead" MB.

Comment: I understand the concept of reflowing - thanks for reminding me of this option.

Comment: With that kind of damage, troubleshooting will require a pro.  If you're asking this question, you probably aren't equipped to do it.  Most computer repair shops aren't equipped, either.  They replace parts and send the old ones to refurbishers who are set up it.  This probably would be too broad for the EE site, also.  Unfortunately it's just too big for the intended scope of a question, and something nobody can really provide a definitive answer to.

Answer (score 1):

I would start by tracing path for the power button and see if there are any damaged to the trace or components along that path.

If the motherboard suffered serious bending, there might be layers within the motherboard that are damaged or trace on the surface that are broken. If that's the case, the only repair you can make is complete replacement of the board.